# Complex function completely simplified and i cant figure out how?

Tags: calculus, derivations

I've been working through some homework on derivatives, particularly complex derivatives, with the following question:

calculate the derivative of function *f* defined on ]-∞ ; -1]U[1;+∞[ by:

f(x) = $(2x<sup>2</sup> +1) &radic;x<sup>2</sup>-1/frac 3x<sup>3</sup>$

in the correction it has been simplified down to :

12x<sup>4</sup>(x<sup>2</sup>-1)+(2x<sup>2</sup>+1)3x<sup>4</sup>-9x<sup>2</sup>(2x<sup>2</sup>+1)(x<sup>2</sup>-1) **/** 9x<sup>6</sup> √x<sup>2</sup>-1

and **then** to :

1 **/** x<sup>4</sup> √x<sup>2</sup>-1

i cant figure out how they've manage to simplify down more than 3 terms to one number on the numerator.. The only thing i've really understood is that 3x<sup>3</sup> seems to have been a factor at some point in the simplification beforehand.
thanks in advance

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your maths; see this [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What happened when you expanded the numerator and canceled like terms?